# Passing a information between views in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-views

so i have this two views, one used to display information and one that returns a file responde. I am trying to download a pdf file using the information on the first view:

```
@login_required()
def detail(request, location_name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return search_in_employees(request)

    current = CurrentInfo()
    pdf_data = current.detail_employees_by_location(location_name)  # this gives me the list of people
    context = {
        'present': current.detail_employees_by_location(location_name),
        'location': location_name,
    }
    print('Data: -------------->', pdf_data)

    return render(request, 'user_area/detail.html', context)
```

and my second view just formats it as a pdf:

```
@login_required()
def download_pdf(request):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    canv = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
    textob = canv.beginText()
    textob.setTextOrigin(inch, inch)
    textob.setFont("Helvetica", 14)

    lines = [
        "Line 1 ",
        "Line 2 ",
        "Line 3 ",
        "Line 4 ",
    ]
    for line in lines:
        textob.textLine(line)

    canv.drawText(textob)
    canv.showPage()
    canv.save()
    buf.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename='employees.pdf')
```

Right now the PDF file only contains dummy data, but how can i pass pdf_data from the first view to the second?

Comment: If you're just formatting it as a pdf in the second function, you don't need to have it as a separate view right? You can just have it as a function and call it in the first view .

Comment: i did it this way because that view is used as a download button basically where it does everything in one shot

Comment: Can you not just send the `location_name` to the second view directly and do the look up in that view?  Or even better create a new function that is not a view called `get_pdf_data` that take the location name and returns the formatted pdf data that you can use in either view

Comment: @Artisan That is my question, how can i directly pass pdf_data to the second view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a function either inside your views.py or inside a helpers.py file in your module:

```py
def get_pdf_data(location_name):
    current = CurrentInfo()
    pdf_data = current.detail_employees_by_location(location_name)
    return pdf_data
```

Then your first view would look like:

```py
@login_required()
def detail(request, location_name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return search_in_employees(request)

    pdf_data = get_pdf_data(location_name)
    context = {
        'present': pdf_data,
        'location': location_name,
    }
    print('Data: -------------->', pdf_data)

    return render(request, 'user_area/detail.html', context)
```

And your second view can use this new function **but only if you send the location_name to the view same as the first view**

```py
@login_required()
def download_pdf(request, location_name):
    pdf_data = get_pdf_data(location_name)

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    canv = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
    textob = canv.beginText()
    textob.setTextOrigin(inch, inch)
    textob.setFont("Helvetica", 14)

    for line in pdf_data:
        textob.textLine(line)

    canv.drawText(textob)
    canv.showPage()
    canv.save()
    buf.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename='employees.pdf')
```